# Angular implement back navigation and back to last component image

Tags: javascript, angular, web

I'm using angular to develop my app and im trying to implement back navigation (User will click a button and will be navigate to the last page).

After the navigation I want the user to see the last state of the page he just return to, for that ill need to save an image of the component(variable values and such).

The user should be able to hit the back button as much as he wants.

Any idea what is the best practice for this kind of implementation?

**Update**

Im not using any state manger

Answer (score 2):

If you use a state manager like Redux, MobX or NgRx, you would easily be able to restore the content of the last visited page.
That's another great advantage of state managers, the ability to provide a cache for free.

Otherwise, you should be able to specifically store the local state (snapshot) of the component into a specific Angular service, so that you can restore it when the component gets reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

for this you can use **Location** provided by angular.

You just have to import the file using:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
```

And make the instance of it in the constructor arguments using :

```
constructor(private location:Location)
```

now just add the following line in your goBack() function called when clicked on button:

```
goBack(){
this.location.back();
```

}

And for storing the state the best way is to use redux and if not you can make services for particular screens and store the data in some observables.
And in your component in **ngOnInit()** first check whether there is some data in service observable by subscribing it and if yes use that data to initialize the variables.

Comment: It is not what the author wants. 
He wants to go back with the previous page reloaded with the exact same state as it was left.

Comment: Yes I have added more to my answer already, please check.